# Number of SSL certificates needed

Tags: ssl-certificate, godaddy

I know virtually nothing about webhosting or SSL encryption. My company has 2 SSL certificates through godaddy for our outlook web app. They are both about to renew, and I just want to make sure we need them both, or at least understand them a bit better. Here is what they say.

(1) webmail.example.org

Standard (Turbo) SSL (1Year)(annual)

(2) webmail.example.org

Standard Multiple Domain (UCC) SSL Up to 5 Domains - 1 year (annual)

However, when I click "Manage Certificate," they both have "Standard UCC SSL" listed under Type.

It feels like we are paying for 2 Certificates but we only need 1. Am I right, or what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one, but which one depends on some factors. The UCC cert is the same thing as the other, plus it includes Alternate Subject Names. A certificate is issued for a particular Subject Name, in your case a web address; but you can put more than one on a cert (useful and/or necessary in cases where one server has multiple sites).

If you only have one web address that uses SSL; you *probably* just want the Standard SSL cert (which will be the cheaper of the two as well). If you have multiple sites, you *probably* want the UCC SSL Cert.

Answer (score 0):

You are right you should only have one SSL.

If you have an SSL valid for a particular (sub)domain that's all you need. A multi domain license is as it says, valid for multiple domain. It's normally cheaper and easier to mange one certificate but it does not do anything different.